# Add value to arraylist execution doesn't stop

Tags: java

I want to build an algorithm that takes into account a list of integers, sort it.

The idea is: iterate over the list of integers, the first value gets into a new list; the following value is compared with the only existing value in the new list and put it in before or after, and so on.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
  
public class SortLists {
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
  
        // list [5,1,4,2,8]
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(5);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(8);

        System.out.println("list : " + list.toString());
        
        // new empty list
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        // iterate over the integer list
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        //int i=2;
        
            // *** 1st iteration - add the value to the list2
            
            if (i == 0){
                list2.add(list.get(i));
            } else {
                
                // *** in the next interations, compare with the existing values in list2
                for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){

                    
                    // *** Note: this if is unecessary but I got an error with list2.get(j)
                    if (j==0){
                        // if the value from list is lower than the only value in list2, put in index 0
                        if (list.get(i) < list2.get(0) ) {
                             list2.add(j,list.get(i));
                        } 
                        
                    }else{
                         
                        if (list.get(i) < list2.get(j) ) {
                             //list2.add(j,list.get(i)); // GIVES ERROR!
                             System.out.println("index "+j+" value "+list.get(i));
                             
                        } else {
                            //list2.add(list.get(i)); //GIVES ERROR!
                            System.out.println("else: index "+j+" value "+list.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //list2.add(1,4); // no error if add manually here
        System.out.println("list2 : " + list2.toString());
        
    }
}
```

The 5 and 1 are correctly inserted in list2.

The other two `list2.add`, if I uncomment them, the execution doesn't stop.

Comment: because, the i or j will always be less than list2.size() or list.size(), it is like, your adding a value to these lists and at the same time the index pointer is moving is next free space and as arraylist is dynamic, i and j will never meet size of these lists. just to validate try running the code with conditions as i < 10(example value) and j < 10(example value) in for loop definition and see your code will work

Comment: You need to break out of the inner loop after adding a value to list2.

Comment: Calling `size()` from within the `for` statement and calling `list.get(i)' within the loop is very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the execution doesn't stop

You get into an infinite loop because in the inner `for` loop you are adding elements to the second list while iterating over the list.

Besides, you are overcomplicating things unnecessarily. Just store the first index for which `list.get(i) < list2.get(j)` is true. If such an index exists, add the i-th element from list one to list two at that index. Otherwise, add the i-th element from list one to the end of list two.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(8);

    System.out.println("list : " + list.toString());

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    list2.add(list.get(0));
    
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
        int index = list2.size();
        for(int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++){
            if (list.get(i) < list2.get(j)){
                index = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        list2.add(index,list.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add j++ after the commented code that gives an error since you are increasing the list size by one. Otherwise it is an infinite loop.